# where can I find smalltalk japanese language support package

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

Friend, I am looking for a japanese language support package for squeak4.1. Can you give some hint on the topics? thanks first!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [here](http://map.squeak.org/package/5279e9cb-1a06-4ddb-8eca-48ca954790d3).

> Description: An install script to
>   set-up Japanese fonts, locale, and
>   some localization patches. This is for
>   developers who use latest Squeak but
>   need to handle Japanese characters.

Comment: Thanks friend! your link is useful to me:)